# Redis: FT.SEARCH fuzzy matching sorting by distance to a provided coordinates

Tags: redis, node-redis, redisearch

i have restaurants collection in my redis DB, the restaurant object stored in as bellow:

```
{
  uid: "T8957Ixo1kRjtw3Nof3Ttase",
  name: "Restaurant name",
  address:
  "751 S 10th St, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania 19140, United States",
  location: "-78.15096902,38.94039013",
}
```

i wonder if it possible to return results sorted by distance

i tried to do `FT.SEARCH index "@name:%%burger%% @location:[-75.153270 39.949655]" SORTBY location ASC`

but it doesn't work at all, How can I achieve that by redisearch?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is only possible with `FT.AGGREGATE`. You will have to use `APPLY` ([documentation here](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/search/aggregations/#list-of-geo-apply-functions)), and then sort by it.

Try something like:

```bash
FT.AGGREGATE index "@name:%%burger%%" APPLY "geodistance(@location, -75.153270, 39.949655)" AS distance SORTBY distance ASC
```

There are some other overloading for `geodistance` in the documentation, you can use the one that suits your environment best.

In addition, you should take another look at the [GEO filter syntax](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/query/#geo-filters). Your query is invalid:

> Geo filters
>
> As of v0.21, it is possible to add geo radius queries directly into the query language with the syntax @field:[{lon} {lat} {radius} {m|km|mi|ft}]. This filters the result to a given radius from a lon,lat point, defined in meters, kilometers, miles or feet. See Redis' own GEORADIUS command for more details as it is used internally for that).
>
> Radius filters can be added into the query just like numeric filters. For example, in a database of businesses, looking for Chinese restaurants near San Francisco (within a 5km radius) would be expressed as: chinese restaurant @location:[-122.41 37.77 5 km].

The query I suggested will work, but if you can give a relevant radius to look in, you might get better performance.

for example:

```bash
FT.AGGREGATE index "@name:%%burger%% @location:[-75.153270 39.949655 5 km]" APPLY "geodistance(@location, -75.153270, 39.949655)" AS distance SORTBY distance ASC
```

will limit the search to a 5km radius.

Hope that helps!